# How to Initialize with my own weights for the second conv layer in a Keras sequential model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a model which has two convolutional layers. I have set new weights for `conv_1` layer successfully but while setting the weights fo `conv_2` layer I am getting an error message:

```
    model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), input_shape=(28,28,1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(6, (3, 3), input_shape=(26,26,1), activation='relu'))

    model.layers[0].set_weights(w1)
    model.layers[2].set_weights(w2)
```

Here, `w1.shape == (3, 3, 1, 8)` and `w2.shape == (3, 3, 1, 6)`. The error message is:

```
ValueError: Layer weight shape (3, 3, 8, 6) not compatible with provided weight shape (3, 3, 1, 6)
```

I am not understanding why it is not setting the weights?

Comment: Each filter in second convolution layer has a shape of `(3, 3, 8)` and since there are 6 filters, the weights would have a shape of `(3, 3, 8, 6)`. However, the `w2` has a shape of `(3, 3, 1, 6)` as you suggested and therefore is incompatible.

Comment: But If I want to set weights with a shape of      (3, 3, 1, 6)  then what should I do. I have to set the weights in this shape. I have changed the input shape of conv2 layer     input_shape=(26,26,1) But still, it is showing me this error.

Comment: Or if I want to input variable-sized channels? How to do that?

Comment: The problem is that the input of the second conv layer is a feature map with 8 channels, but you are providing filters weights with one channel i.e. `(3,3,1)` and this is not possible. One alternative is to use the same weights for all the channels in a filter.

Comment: How can use the same weights for all the channels in a filter? Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments section one alternative is to use the same weights for all the channels in a filter. To do so, you can easily repeat the values of `w2` eight times to get an array of shape `(3,3,8,6)`:

```
w2 = w2.repeat(8,axis=2)
w2.shape
# (3,3,8,6)
```

Comment: Thank you but After compiling your code, its shape is    (3, 3, 48).

Comment: @M.ahmed Are you sure that the `w2.shape` before doing this is `(3,3,1,6)`? If that's not the case (which seems to be `(3,3,6)`) first run `w2 = np.expand_dims(w2, axis=2)` and then run the code above.